How can I make show some description in my VsCode with tsDoc? VSCode IntelliSense dosen't work
I want to show description that *.ts file's overall description.
I wrote comment in top of the *.ts file. Like that.
effect-sound.ts
/**
 * @file effect-sound.ts
 * @description I want to show description.
 * @see somthing....
 */

other files <-- It do not working!
import * as effectSound from 'effect-sound.ts';

VSCode's IntelliSense dosen't show nothing.
How can I describe about whole of file?

You might need to add another tsdoc comment after your initial one which will be ignored. Relevant issue

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
